How to change the background color of a DataGrid fixed header in Blazorise?
I have been attempting to change the background color of a fixed header inside a DataGrid object in Blazorise for quite some time today, but to no avail, have not succeed in getting the background color changed.
Here is what I am getting

The weird thing is when you remove the defined FixedHeader option in the code shown below, the styling appears to work.
<DataGrid TItem="PersonData"
          Data="@items"
          PageSize="300"
          Responsive
          HeaderRowStyling="@HeaderStyling()"
          RowStyling='(x,y ) => y.Style = "background-color: #374151; color: #ffffff;"'
          Bordered="true"
          RowSelectable="args => false"
          FixedHeader
        >
        <DataGridColumns>
            <DataGridColumn .../>
            <DataGridColumn .../>
            <DataGridColumn .../>
            <DataGridColumn .../>
            <DataGridColumn .../>
            <DataGridColumn .../>
                <DisplayTemplate>
                    <Button Color="Color.Success"> View </Button>
                </DisplayTemplate>
            </DataGridColumn>
        </DataGridColumns>
</DataGrid>

The styling I have for the HeaderRowStyling variable only works half the time when the  FixedHeader option is present. What will happen is the font color will change to white which is correct, but the desired background color does not change when the FixedHeader option is present.
The styling is very simple and is implemented below
<style>
    .custom_header_styling {
        background-color: #1F2937;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
</style>

@code {
    private DataGridRowStyling HeaderStyling()
    {
        return new DataGridRowStyling
        {
            Class = "custom_header_styling"
        };
    }
}

I have looked into the Developer Tools on my browser for the styling because it is clearly being defined but something must be overriding it. It looks like the custom styling is being overwritten by the FixedHeader background styling.


Is there a way to overcome this limitation or will I have to settle with not using the FixedHeader option if I want custom table styling?

It happens because fixed header selector has a higher specifity. You have two options

add an important tag to the background-color
copy the fixed header selector and just add an additional class, ie. custom_header_styling

